# How to play (or replace) flash SWF files with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, flash, audio, swfobject

A while back I had hired someone to help me set up a php based poker game for my site.  It works ok, but I had to remove the flash SWF sound effects because it was causing all sorts of problems with some browsers.
I've been able to get it to work pretty well by removing the sound, but wondering if I can replace the swf sound effects with javascript?

I don't know a whole lot about this stuff, can anyone point me in the right direction?

This is the code in my php files which sends the sound through flash, when deleting this, the program functions much smoother, but I'd like to get the sound back if at all possible (and can switch out the swf files for a different format if needed):

```
var flashHtml = '<';
flashHtml += 'OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"';
flashHtml += 'codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=5,0,0,0"'; 
flashHtml += ' WIDTH="1" HEIGHT="1" id="mian" ALIGN="">'; 
flashHtml += '<PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="sounds/<? echo $sfx; ?>"><PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high>'; 
flashHtml += '<EMBED src="sounds/<? echo $sfx; ?>" quality=high bgcolor=#FFFFFF WIDTH="1" HEIGHT="1" NAME="main" '; 
flashHtml += 'ALIGN="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></EMBED>'; 
flashHtml += '</OBJECT>';
 document.getElementById('flashObject').innerHTML = flashHtml;
```

and I had deleted this

```
          <div id="flashObject"></div>
```

Any suggestions?  I had searched through some Q's here and tried using soundmanager 2 JS, but have had little luck getting anything that doesn't break the site.  Should I just omit the sound, or is there a solution which isn't too complicated?

Comment: Use HTML5 Audio and the respective Javascript API.

Comment: I've tried something like this:  var audio = new Audio('audio_file.swf');
audio.play();    Do I need to change the swf to mp3?

Comment: Read this https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video